# Xaml: how to call a method whose name is stored in string?

Tags: c#, xaml

```
string combo_value = cmbox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
object value = typeof(JsonObject).GetMethod("combo_value")
                                 .Invoke(jsonObject.rates,new Type[0]);
 Label_value.Text = value;
```

Comment: Other than the double quotes for `combo_value` inside the `GetMethod` call, I don't see any problem in your code. What is your actual problem?

Comment: You do realise major woe will ensue, if any methods are overloaded, or the methods you want to call have different signatures?

Comment: Please provide more information about the error you encounter.

Comment: i have got following error in vs2013: Error 3 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod' and no extension method 'GetMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert the result of the invocation to a string -- either cast (if it's actually a string), or by using `ToString()`:

```
string methodName = cmbox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
object methodOwner = jsonObject.rates;
object[] methodParameters = new Type[0];   // this is the same as having no parameters

// invoke methodName on the instance jsonObject.rates, with no parameters
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Invoking the method named '{0}' on the object '{1}' with parameters '{2}'",
    methodName, methodOwner, string.Join(", ", methodParameters);

object value = typeof(JsonObject).GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(methodOwner, methodParameters);
if (value != null)
    Label_value.Text = value.ToString();
```

Note that the two parameters of `Invoke` are 1) the object on which to invoke the method, and 2) the method's parameters.  I see that you're passing an empty array as the parameter array -- this would be an odd way to pass no parameters to the method (may as well just pass `null`).  So I suspect that is not what you meant to do.  You have to make sure that the `object[]` that you pass to `Invoke` matches the signature of the method you are invoking.

Comment: i have got following  error:                                                                 Error 3 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod' and no extension method 'GetMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)